# Can a django template be referenced from within a loop on another template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django template which loops over many notes/comments.  As a simplified example take this.

```
{% for note in notes %}
    <p>
        Date added:    {{ note.date_added }}
        {{ note.note|urlize|url_target_blank|linebreaks }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then on the same page I have a form to add a new note.  This note form is an ajax form and returns the newly submitted note back to the page and appends it at the end of the already existent note area.

I don't like this because I have to maintain the same html structure both in the page for the initial load, as well as in the response from the ajax form.

Is there a way to put a call to another template, inside of a template (in this for loop) so I can maintain the note formatting in one location only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the "include" tag: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: How dumb of me, I'd even used it before.  Bad evening I guess.  Any idea why I'd be unable to use custom template tags in that included document?  My custom "url_target_blank" works fine unless in the included document.  Why would custom template tags be treated any differently?

Comment: or I didn't load the extras file in the second template...that fixes it.  Nevermind.  So if anyone is reading this in the future, you must load your custom template tags in a template that you include.

Comment: What's the performance like when used inside a loop like this?

Comment: Performance is going to hit really bad. Its going to eat a lot of CPU at the same time if template is not cached then it will become I/O bound. Currently I am stuck there not knowing what to do. :(
Suggestion not to use include in a for loop.